# Left Icon in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to add an Left Icon to my TextInputLayout, but text get over the Icon.
When I add a padding, everything move together.

I tried with

```
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
 android:drawablePadding="50dp"
 android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
```

But it is not working !
I should implement a LinearLayout horizontal for each row, but I would like to be sure there is no easier way to do it

Here is my code layout:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_calle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_calle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
                android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
                android:hint="Calle"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Why not use a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`? If you do, you can use `android:layout_toRightOf`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I could do it, but I would "duplicate" my code quantity ( I have like 40 fields, so I would like optimize it )

Comment: If you have 40 fields why not use a ListView, then fill the ListView with each row?

Comment: well I have 40 non homogen fields. So ListView in not so adapted, and my experience with forms + listview is that it is a pain in the ass!

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Can you give an update?

Comment: Sorry, I left this project, so it will be difficult for me to give feedback! I'm no longer Android programmer!

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Can you please choose an answer?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest `Design` library, all you need for both `Design` and `AppCompat` is:

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'`

Try using both the Design's library `TextInputLayout` and AppCompat's `AppCompatEditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/loginHint">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
        android:minWidth="350dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/loginHint"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I think, `minWidth` can be omited and `layout_width` set to `match_parent` and color properties are not related to showing Icon. there are also `drawableEnd` and 'drawableRight' to show an icon at the end.

Comment: This example works also with the new component `TextInputEditText`.

Answer (score 18):

With the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can change the left icon in the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) using the **`app:startIconDrawable`** attribute.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="Hint text"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        ...>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can it be clickable? i mean left drawable takes its own click and other input field part its own

Comment: @UsmanRana Yes. You can use `textInputLayout.setStartIconOnClickListener`

Answer (score 5):

> Here is my code layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_user"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_user"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="User Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**android:drawablePadding="10dp"**

Its work

Comment: This doesn't work with supportLibVersion 24.2.0. I had to downgrade to 24.1.1

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug that was reported on Android's Issue Tracker

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225836

and it's now been fixed on the latest release of the Design Support Library (v25.0.1). Just add the required dependency to the build gradle...

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
}
```

Comment: you are right, now i am updated android support respository to  revision 40 then i am used   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'. Now my drawable right issue solved thanks.

Comment: saved my day. same problem was with me

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, when adding `passwordToggleEnabled` it automatically adding the eye icon on the right and the `drawableLeft` was gone. so you have to remove the `drawableLeft` and just use the `drawableStart`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_calle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_calle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="50dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
            android:hint="Calle"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using material input layout so you just need to add one line in input layout's xml code

```
app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_content_paste_24"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Currently its a bug on Layout.
You can try giving leftPadding to EditText or give some blank_spaces before the text.

Answer (score 0):

Using material library, you can set custom icon using `endIconMode="custom"`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/date_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/date_end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:text="30 feb" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```